# superclass to see subclasses methods

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a

```
class Game {}

class Game1 extends Game{}

class Game2 extends Game1{ 
  void method1(){};
}
```

but when I do,

```
Game game = new Game2 (); //compiles fine and all is ok
game.method1(); //gives me error method1 is not defined for type Game
```

how can I solve this? Game is the super super class..

Comment: Please display the code of your inheritance. Do you call the super() from each of your constructors?

Comment: You should read some tutorials about Inheritance, e.g. [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: @user3337714 *"Do you call the super() from each of your constructors?"* Why should she do that manually?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call methods on a sub class for a variable cast to a super class, then you need to cast it back down to the subclass. On the other hand, if a `Game` object needs to know methods on a `Game2` object, maybe you should declare Game as an abstract class with an abstract method that Game2 and Game1 must implement:

```
public abstract class Game {
    public abstract void method1();
}

public class Game1 extends Game {
    public void method1() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class Game2 extends Game {
    public void method1() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU...have a god day !!!

Comment: a question, if Game1 implements void method1() and Game2 doesnt 
is there going to be an error at compile time?
because I still don't get why I should implement by force a method in a subclass if the parent class already has it that I can call from the sub....this is the whole beauty of inheritance no? :)

Comment: I got it. working fine :) one abstract, an extension 1 and another extension 2. Implemented methods in extension 1; call from extension 2 of type abstract = new extension2.
all is good..thank you soo much! :)